# TypeDef error between classes C++

Tags: c++, class, typedef

Im a fairly new programmer so I may not be understanding typedef correctly.

I have 2 classes Enemy.cpp and AI.cpp. 
My AI.cpp needs values from Enemy.cpp to be able to process its movements etc. In AI.cpp I hold pointers to values such as position, speed and an enum for the direction the enemy is facing.

The Errors I get are listed below. If there is a more simple way to link an enum variable between classes, im all ears.

below is a working example of the error.

```
///////MAIN.H/////////////

#ifndef  _MAIN_H_
#define _MAIN_H_



#endif // ! _MAIN_H_

///////////////////////////

////////MAIN.CPP///////////

#include "AI.h"
#include "Enemy.h"

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    Enemy enemy; 

}

//////////////////////////////

//////////ENEMY.H///////////////

#ifndef _ENEMY_H_
#define _ENEMY_H_ 

#include "AI.h"

class Enemy 
{

public: 

    Enemy();

    enum Facing
    {
        LEFT = 0,
        RIGHT
    };



protected:

    AI* EnemiesAI; 
    //try this as a pointer
    Facing EnemyDirection;

};


#endif

//////////////////////////////////

///////////ENEMY.CPP////////////////

#include "Enemy.h"

Enemy::Enemy()
{
    EnemiesAI = new AI; 

    EnemiesAI->LinkEnemyToAI(&EnemyDirection);
}

////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////AI.H//////////////

#ifndef _AI_H_
#define _AI_H_

#include "Enemy.h"

class AI
{
public: 

    /*this needs to be a pointer, otherwise I have to pass the 
    value into AI on every update*/
    typedef Enemy::Facing *ThisFacing; //Error 3

    void LinkEnemyToAI(ThisFacing facing);

private: 
    //This is a pointer to a Enemy::Facing object
    ThisFacing mFacing; 


};

#endif

///////////////////////////////////////

////////////////AI.CPP/////////////////

#include "AI.h"

void AI::LinkEnemyToAI(ThisFacing facing)
{
    mFacing = facing;
}

////////////////////////////////////////
```

Error   C2653   'Enemy': is not a class or namespace name   ExampleOfTypeDefError   c:\dev\projects\exampleoftypedeferror\exampleoftypedeferror\ai.h    11

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    ExampleOfTypeDefError   c:\dev\projects\exampleoftypedeferror\exampleoftypedeferror\ai.h    11

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C3646   'mFacing': unknown override specifier   ExampleOfTypeDefError   c:\dev\projects\exampleoftypedeferror\exampleoftypedeferror\ai.h    17

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    ExampleOfTypeDefError   c:\dev\projects\exampleoftypedeferror\exampleoftypedeferror\ai.h    17

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2660   'AI::LinkEnemyToAI': function does not take 1 arguments ExampleOfTypeDefError   c:\dev\projects\exampleoftypedeferror\exampleoftypedeferror\enemy.cpp   7

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'ThisFacing'   ExampleOfTypeDefError   c:\dev\projects\exampleoftypedeferror\exampleoftypedeferror\ai.h    13

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   ExampleOfTypeDefError   c:\dev\projects\exampleoftypedeferror\exampleoftypedeferror\enemy.h 23

Comment: Would you mind posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your posted code doesn't seem compilable because there are `public:` and `Protected:` in storange positions.

Comment: You have `Protected:` and `Private:` in your code. Are you programming on a phone with autocorrect?

Comment: you cant include AI.h in Enemy.h and Enemy.h in AI.h at the same time. Rethink your design (imho circular dependencies are always bad) or use a forward declaration

Comment: Besides the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please copy-paste the actual error messages (complete, in full, with possible informational notes, and without modifications) into your question.

Comment: `Enemy::Facing *` (a.k.a. `ThisFacing`) is not the same type as `Enemy::Facing`. `&` means different things in types and in expressions. Review the chapters on pointers and references in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: edits made @tobi303
I understand circular dependencies and it is on my list of things to do. As you can see though I use #ifndef to avoid serious problems for now.

Comment: edits made @someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using include-guards here doesn't help really, because `Enemy.h` depends on `AI.h` which depends on `Enemy.h` and so on forever.

You have to break that chain, and the easiest way to break it is through something called *forward declarations*.

If you look closer in the `Enemy.h` header file, all it uses of the `AI` class is to declare a member variable which is a pointer to `AI`. That means you don't need the full definition of `AI`, you only need to tell the compiler that the class `AI` exists. Something like

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H

class AI;  // Forward declaration of the AI class    

class Enemy 
{
public: 
    Enemy();

    enum Facing
    {
        LEFT = 0,
        RIGHT
    };

protected:
    AI* EnemiesAI; 
    //try this as a pointer
    Facing EnemyDirection;
};

#endif // ENEMY_H
```

Now in the `Enemy.cpp` file you still need to `#include "AI.h"` since the full definition of the class is needed there.

This forward declaration isn't really possible in the `AI.h` header file, since in it you use the enumeration `Enemy::Facing`. However, since `Enemy.h` no longer includes `AI.h` there's no longer the circular dependency.

Also note that I changed the header guard macro to not have leading underscores, since all symbols with a leading underscore follower by an upper-case letter is reserved in all scopes. See e.g. [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, @someprogrammerdude. 
Does that actually resolve the errors that Im getting in the example code?
you havent specified that it does. 
My code does compile so I do not believe that this is the main issue here.

Comment: @DanJones Yes it will solve some of the errors you list. And yes I said what it does, it exchanges the `#include "AI.h"` to `class AI;`, i.e. it makes a forward declaration of the `AI` class instead of including the  AI.h` header file.

Comment: Thanks, thats done it. I had some other issues with other classes which i had to resolve aswell. But my code is now compiling correctly. 
I will have to be more aware of circular dependencies in the future.
@someprogrammerdude